# Can every polynomial be factored into constant and linear complex factors?

Tags: analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring

That is, can any polynomial, $a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1x^1+a_0$, be expressed $b_0\left(x + b_1\right)\left(x + b_2\right)\ldots \left(x + b_n\right)$ where $b_i \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: do you want $b_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{C}$? (the first one is usually for integers, the latter for complex numbers)

Comment: isn't it $b_i\in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of algebra states that every non-constant polynomial in complex numbers splits into linear factors in the field of complex numbers.

Comment: You two are right, that was a typo.

Comment: @Peter, did you mean the [FT of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra)?

Comment: Yes, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Normally you would see $-$'s in the factors though, because then the $b_n$'s are the roots of the polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Every polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ can be factored into linear or quadratic terms. If you have a real quadratic, it can be factored into linear terms over $\mathbb{C}$. This is what is meant by the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is an algebraic completion of $\mathbb{R}$: $\mathbb{C}$ has the roots of all polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

The only condition of the [fundamental theorem of algebra (FTA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) is that the polynomial must be non-constant, i.e. some $a_i \ne 0$ for an $i > 0$. Then it states that there is a unique factorisation
$$\sum_{i=0}^k a_i x^k = b_0 \prod_{i=1}^k (x-b_i)$$